# Call a specific page in Wordpress from PHP with WPML

Tags: php, wordpress, wpml

I have a Wordpress template which works with Blocks. You map a page in a Block and then you add this block on your Home. However, one Block doesn't have a mapping option, so I did the following.

I opened the PHP file from this specific block and add a code to call a page with the ID.

```
<?php
$my_id = 1575;
$post_id_1575 = get_post($my_id);
$content = $post_id_1575->post_content;
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
$content = str_replace(']]>', ']]>', $content);
echo $content;
?>
```

The page has an `ID=1575`. However, when I use WPML to duplicate the page and create it in another language, it creates a new page with a new ID. Is there any way to check the language on the PHP that is selected and then call another page id?

For example:

```
<?php

if (language == "en") {
    $my_id = 1575;
} else {
    $my_id = 1580;
}
$post_id_1575 = get_post($my_id);
    $content = $post_id_1575->post_content;
    $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
    $content = str_replace(']]>', ']]>', $content);
    echo $content;
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the currently selected language in WPML, use the following code:

```
global $sitepress;
$language = $sitepress->get_current_language();
```

That will return a two letter language code like 'fr' for French or 'it' for Italian.

However, I think what you're trying to do is find out the link to a particular post in a different language. If you just need to do this on case by case basis, Barry Kooij [wrote a function](http://www.barrykooij.com/getting-the-url-for-a-translated-page-based-on-the-url-of-a-different-language-using-wpml/) to accomplish this.

If what you want is to give users the option to switch the language they view a post in, you should consider using WPML's language switcher or [creating a custom WPML language switcher](http://wpml.org/documentation/getting-started-guide/language-setup/custom-language-switcher/).